# Websocket Tomcat vs Websocket Netty

Tags: tomcat, websocket, netty

I have a project using Websockets with JSR-356 @ServerEndpoint with Tomcat 8.

Would it be worth to improve performance to move to Netty instead (with something like Vert.x for example) ?